# ASP:GridView BoundField with custom objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I'm passing my GridView a List<> of custom objects. Each object contains other objects.

This works:

```
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="TableContent" ItemStyle-Width="100" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderText="Clicks" HeaderStyle-CssClass="OrangeTableHeaders">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# string.Format("{0:n0}",((MyProject.AppCode.AdGroup)Container.DataItem).AdStatistics.Clicks)%></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

But is there a way to accomplish this with a BoundField instead of a TemplateField?

IE, this doesn't work - am I just formatting the call incorrectly?
Thanks!

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AdStatistics.Clicks" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a public property say `AdStatisticsClicks` inside your custom object like:

```
public string AdStatisticsClicks
{
   return string.Format("{0:n0}", AdStatistics.Clicks);
}
```

and use like:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AdStatisticsClicks" HeaderText="Clicks" />
```